# DotNetOpenAuth OAuth 1.0a Consumer automation

Tags: oauth, dotnetopenauth, consumer

I've question regarding automation with oAuth 1.0a. I need to access a REST API at a oAuth provider on behalf of a user. The provider has oAuth version 1.0a implemented.

At forehand excuse my ignorance on oAuth, it's new territory for me.

I'm working on a .NET MVC 5 project and installed the NuGet Package as follows: "Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer". This installed the following:
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.4.3.4.13329' with respect to project '*projectname*', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'... successfully installed dependencies and the DotNetOpenAuth consumer package.

My goal is to access a REST API when triggered by an external source which is not human. In short, a controller is triggered by an external process and sends data to my application. Next, I will need to access the REST API of the provider in order to process the received data. So, no human eyes or hands are available to login or copy a verifier of some sort.

I've been looking around, read about oAuth and the DNOA library. I kinda found that I have to obtain a RequestToken to start off with. I'm using the following code to achieve this:

```
InMemoryTokenManager tm = new InMemoryTokenManager("**consumerkey**", "**secret**");
var serviceProvider = GetServiceDescription();
var consumer = new DesktopConsumer(serviceProvider, tm);
string reqToken;
consumer.RequestUserAuthorization(null, null, out reqToken);
```

I read about the InMemoryTokenManager, ServiceProviderDescription, DesktopConsumer and that is pretty clear to me. Although I'm not surefooted about using DesktopConsumer instead of WebConsumer..

Now, I need to get a verification code from the Provider. But how to proceed next in order to get it? 
I've looked at the UserAuthorizationResponse object which contains a property exactly for this purpose but I'm unable to figure out how to retrieve this.

With the request token and verification code I should be able to get a AuthorizedTokenResponse object and perform the REST API calls.

Can anyone help me out on this?